# Why does window.navigator.userAgent show wrong Firefox version?

Tags: javascript, firefox

This question is related to the Firefox browser version in Windows systems.

When I try to access the browser version using

```
window.navigator.userAgent
```

the output shows version 24, but if I check the version via Firefox menu > Help > *About Firefox*, the version is 32.

[image: Firefox version]

How is that possible?

Any one came across this type of issue? I have no clear clue on how to modify the browser built in functions.

Comment: Manual UserAgent? Probably you did it and you don't remember. Or it's an ugly update bug.

Comment: My Firefox correctly reports 32, in both Firebug and the native devtools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can have two reasons.

1. **Exposed user agent changed by user**
   There are add-ons for Firefox like [User Agent Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/user-agent-switcher/), which allow you to change the user agent string exposed to JavaScript via `window.navigator.userAgent` and in network requests within the `User-Agent` header.
   The user agent can also manually be modified by going to `about:config` and changing the preference `general.useragent.override`.
2. **Bug in Firefox**
   If the `general.useragent.override` property isn't available within `about:config` or contains an empty string, this is likely a bug in Firefox, which you should [report to Mozilla](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/).